# Reduce spatial data set size using HDBSCAN

Tags: python, machine-learning, geolocation, dbscan, hdbscan

I am trying to reduce the spatial data set size by clustering them and finding the center point for the clusters. I referenced to [this](https://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/) article (which uses `DBSCAN`)and it kind of helped except that now the data set size has increased, I am now unable to go forward b/c of memory errors. So, i switched to next best thing `HDBSCAN`. But, I am getting some strange results.
First, I am using following:

```
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_samples=1, min_cluster_size=25, algorithm='prims_balltree', metric='haversine')
```

This is able to provide clusters but when I dig into these clusters, they are practically the same. e.g. two clusters comprising of similar geo-locations. My idea is that it should have been a single cluster.

Second, To resolve such the above problem, I tried using `cluster_selection_epsilon=0.1/6371` to cluster geo-locations within `100m` in same cluster.

```
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_samples=5, min_cluster_size=10, metric='haversine',cluster_selection_epsilon=0.1/6371)
```

But, then i get this one big cluster with over hundred thousand points and while plotting on `folium` I found that those points are not within `100m` apart, rather they are separate clusters of points that are mre than 100m apart.
I am probably not using the `min_cluster_size` in terms of `haversine` metric.
Can someone explain what's happening. How can I achieve my goal of clustering similar geo-locations. and narrow down the cluster to one center point?